# How to disable emojis system-wide?

Tags: emoji

I never want to see an emoji again.
I have seen instructions for disabling them in specific apps, but I want a nuclear option.

How do I get rid of them for all apps, all users, all contexts?

I'm on OSX 10.10 Yosemite

Comment: An Emoji is character like any other character (as defined in Unicode).
 
If you hide an emoji system-wide, it's like you would remove the character 'A' or '&'. This is definitely not a good idea.

Comment: I'd be curious what apps let you "disable" emojis.  I suspect this is not for the Unicode characters, but for some other forms, where normal text like :-) gets automatically translated into graphics.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler emojis are _not_ like other characters in many obvious ways, which I find annoying and distracting. If there were some means to cause them to appear like other characters, I'd live with them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be able to remove Apple's Color Emoji font, but you cannot remove it with FontBook. Instead, go to /System/Library/Fonts/ and drag "Apple Color Emoji.ttf" to the Trash. You must authenticate yourself as an administrator to do this. I haven't tested this, and I don't know if your computer will catch fire.

Comment: This seems to have accomplished close enough to what I want. Emojis are now appearing either as simple black-and-white charcters, or some kind of generic "unicode-not-available" block-looking character. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this requires disabling SIP on later OS X(macOS) versions.